# Expo React Native extra space at the top and bottom of the app on iPhone 11

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, expo

I have a problem where there is extra space above the  at the top and below the tab navigation at the bottom of the app when running it on an iPhone 11.  I don't see them on earlier device versions.  Does anybody have any pointers on how to get rid of the space?  (The bits in the red boxes in the image below)

[image: iphone react native app with extra space top and bottom]

I'm using Expo SDK 36.0.0 and React Native 0.61.5.

Thanks!

=======

Comment: you have used flex:1 right?

Comment: @GauravRoy yes, and SafeAreaView